# How to read separate day, separate month and separate year from Mysql which is in form 10/12/2004

Tags: mysql, pdo

SUBSTR(`staff_dob`,1,2) as day,SUBSTR(`staff_dob`,4,2) as month,SUBSTR(`staff_dob`,7,4) as year

This code is perfect for 10/12/2004= 10 day, 12 month, 2004 year
But 1/3/2004 is gives= 1/ day, 2/ month, 004 year
I need same format answer from same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUBSTR(s.staff_dob,1,2) as day,SUBSTR(s.staff_dob,4,2) as month,SUBSTR(s.staff_dob,7,4) as year

Answer (score 0):

you can use YEAR(date) as year , MONTH (date) as month and DAY

Comment: It doesn't work due to this is inserted via concatenate of day field, month field and year field from php. Not directly used date() function so.

Comment: So you can change the insert to be date no ?

Comment: no no i can't change. i need insert in this format.( i can't  directly used date () function due to some validation problem)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to put a 0 before, like this: "01/03/2004"